# Making a better summary statistics table with plyr in R

Tags: r, plyr

Every time I get a new data set the first thing I do is check out the summary statistics. The `summary` function does a pretty good job, but I'm frequently interested in standard deviations, quantiles with different breakpoints, number of observations, etc. Also, the presentation of `summary` isn't really the easiest way to digest or what you see in journals (i.e., `summary` is horizontal instead of vertical).

For example, here is what I get from summary with some made up data.

```
> library(plyr)
> library(reshape2)
> my.data <- data.frame(firm = factor(rep(letters[1:5], each = 5)), returns = rnorm(n = 5 * 5), leverage = rep(c(0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7), each = 5) + .... [TRUNCATED] 
> my.summary <- summary(my.data)
> my.summary
 firm     returns           leverage     
 a:5   Min.   :-1.6765   Min.   :0.2863  
 b:5   1st Qu.:-0.6945   1st Qu.:0.3929  
 c:5   Median :-0.1930   Median :0.5061  
 d:5   Mean   :-0.1159   Mean   :0.5009  
 e:5   3rd Qu.: 0.4323   3rd Qu.:0.6011  
       Max.   : 1.1915   Max.   :0.7093
```

But let's say I really want something more like this.

```
> my.manual.summary <- data.frame(mean = c(mean(my.data$returns), mean(my.data$leverage)), median = c(median(my.data$returns), median(my.data$leverage .... [TRUNCATED] 
> rownames(my.manual.summary) <- c("returns", "leverage")
> my.manual.summary
               mean     median        sd
returns  -0.1158633 -0.1929571 0.6996548
leverage  0.5008895  0.5061301 0.1453381
```

For this small data set (i.e., just a few firm characteristics) this is easy. But I have more or what to do more statistics or more slicing-dicing, it can get tedious.

I tried this with `reshape2` and `plyr`, but get an error.

```
> my.melted.data <- melt(my.data)
Using firm as id variables
> my.improved.summary <- ddply(my.melted.data[, -1], .(variable), c("mean", "median", "sd"), na.rm = T)
Error in proto[[i]] <- fs[[i]](x, ...) : 
  more elements supplied than there are to replace
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In mean.default(X[[1L]], ...) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
2: In mean.default(sort(x, partial = half + 0L:1L)[half + 0L:1L]) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
3: In var(as.vector(x), na.rm = na.rm) : NAs introduced by coercion
4: In mean.default(X[[1L]], ...) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

This leaves me with two questions:

1. What am I doing wrong with `ddply`?
2. Am I re-inventing the wheel here? Given that this is table 1 in everything I read and write, is there an existing solution that I haven't found?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try the `stat.desc` in the `pastecs` package. You can use it on your data set by calling `stat.desc(my.data)`. To get the output in the format you desire, you need to (a) transpose the data frame, (b) remove non-numeric variables and (c) only retain the summary statistics columns you require

Answer (score 3):

I found the conceptual error in my code above. Because `mean`, `median`, and `sd` operate on a vector, I need to feed them a specific vector in the data frame that `ddply` creates based on `.variables`. (I was incorrectly applying an example from the manual, which used data frame operators `nrow` and `ncol`.) Here's the correct code:

```
my.melted.data <- melt(my.data)
my.improved.summary <- ddply(
  my.melted.data
  , .(variable)
  , function(x) data.frame(
    mean = mean(x$value)
    , median = median(x$value)
    , sd = sd(x$value)
  )
)
```

Ramnath's solution is easier, but this is extensible to any type summary stats you might want.